# Increase sorting performance for a large inputfile

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I have write a sorting of a files to different height. Now the sort over a for loop is realy slow. Is there a nice way to do this:

```
TKE=pd.DataFrame()
for high_value in range(minimum_range_m, maximum_range_m+display_resolution_m,display_resolution_m):
    globals()['data_high_sort_%s'%high_value]=pd.DataFrame()
    globals()['TKE_%s'%high_value]=pd.DataFrame()
    print('Sort height: ', high_value)
    for ind_dataframe in range(len(data_month)):
        if data_month.iloc[ind_dataframe]['Altitude_[m]']== high_value:
            globals()['data_high_sort_%s'%high_value] = globals()['data_high_sort_%s'%high_value].append(data_month.iloc[ind_dataframe][:]) #,ignore_index=True

gc.collect()
```

Comment: Try different sorting algorithm. All have their strengths and weaknesses. Like buble sort, selection sort etc. Read on those and choose what suits you best.

Comment: sort was a good solution. :)